# how to add custom Icons fonts on nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to use Icon Fonts on my NativeScript app.

So I followed the [oficial documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts) and those were my steps:

(1) - Downloaded the ttf files into my app/fonts folder:

[image]

(2) - On my `app.css` I declared the font global class like so:

```
.fa {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-regular-400", "fa-solid- 
  900";
 }

.fa-solid {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
}
```

(3) - Then on my html component:

```
<Label text="&#xf019;" class="far"></Label>
```

But My Icon does not appear on the screen. I am using NativeScript 6+ with Angular 8.

Any Help ?

Comment: Was it a typo? Your class name reads `far` but your class definition is `fa` / `fa-solid`.

Comment: As Manoj mentioned class name should be `fa`

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out why the Font Icons wasn't showing up!

I was using NativeScript 5.1 and since version 6.0 was released I migrated the project:

`tns migrate`

The problem is that I was using NS with Angular 8 and according to the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts#using-icon-fonts-in-nativescript) I have to place my fonts on the project's root folder.

> In your root application folder (This is the app folder for NativeScript Core, and the src folder for Angular 6+), create a folder called fonts and place the .ttf there.

So, Clearly the problem was that my fonts folder was inside `/app` when it should be inside `/src` folder.

It took me too long to realize that because for some strange reason my imported text fonts like 'Montserrat.tff' was working just fine. So I thought the problem was related with NativeScript or whatever.

In short, the Wrong way to do it with NativeScript and Angular 6+:

[image]

The right way:

[image]

I hope this helps newcomers who may stumble in the same problem/situation.